# Drawing cylinders using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do you draw the following cylinders in latex using tikzpicture?

[image: What I want to achieve]

I have managed to learn how to draw rectangles, triangle and cuboid so far. However I have never drawn that involves circular sides.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please include code showing what you've tried. There are also a lot of questions on this site about drawing cylinders, as well as examples in the TikZ manual.

For example, a few moments looking at the `shapes.geometric` library suggests something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, minimum height=15mm, minimum width=7.5mm] {};
  \draw [<->] ([xshift=5pt]a.before bottom) -- ([xshift=5pt]a.after top) node [midway, right] {$h$};
  \draw [<->] ([yshift=-5pt]a.bottom) -- ([yshift=-5pt]a.bottom -| a.before bottom) node [midway, below] {$r$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cylinder]

Comment: How do you change the location of the cylinder in a more general Tikz picture? I can only manage to have it at (0,0)

Comment: @AnderBiguri Just place the `\node` wherever you want it. The other bits are relative to the node `a`, so `a` is the only one you need to explicitly put as you wish.