# how to use the arc and shade function to draw an amazing cylinder shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, arc

I want to draw a cylinder with tikz, I haven't used `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` indicader in the answer [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277065)
here I am going to complete my figure to show the arc behind in dashed, **i want to use `\draw [dashed, red]({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0)arc (180:360:{0.31*cos(70)} and -0.3);`indicated on page 152 in the [pgfmanual](ftp://ftp.ist.utl.pt/pub/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) in the manual** also I would like to add some color to cylinder using shade function.to have an amazing  cylinder shape.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\textcolor{purple}{
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1.3,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.3) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
 \fill[](0,0,0) circle(0.3pt) node[left]{$O$};}
 \textcolor{blue}{\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (1.3,0,0.3) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (0,1.,0.3) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (0,0,1.6) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}

 \fill[](0,0,0.3) circle(0.3pt) node[left]{$G$};
 \draw[thick] (0,0,0) circle(0.31);
\draw[thick] (0,0,0.3) circle(0.31);
\draw[thick] (0,0,0.6) circle(0.31);
\draw[thick, dotted] ({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0.6)--({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0);
\draw[thick, dotted] ({0.31*cos(270)},{0.31*sin(270)},0.6)--({0.31*cos(270)},{0.31*sin(270)},0);
\draw [dashed, red]({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0)arc (180:360:{0.31*cos(70)} and -0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazingly, the amazing pgfmanual already has amazing cylinders in. I add one to your code. And the statement about the arc I don't understand...

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,intersections,calc}
\pgfset{ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138834/121799
  Cylinder end fill/.initial=,
  Cylinder body fill/.initial=,
  Cylinder end shade/.initial=,
  Cylinder body shade/.initial=}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{Cylinder}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritanchorborder[from=cylinder]%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{center}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{shape center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{mid west}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{south east}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{before top}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{top}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{after top}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{before bottom}%
  \inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{bottom}\inheritanchor[from=cylinder]{after bottom}%
  \behindbackgroundpath{%
    \ifpgfcylinderusescustomfill%
      \getcylinderpoints%
      \pgf@x\xradius\relax%
      \advance\pgf@x-\outersep\relax%
      \edef\xradius{\the\pgf@x}%
      \pgf@y\yradius\relax%
      \advance\pgf@y-\outersep\relax%
      \edef\yradius{\the\pgf@y}%
      {%
        \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
        \pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\afterbottom}%
        \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\beforetop\pgf@y-\pgf@y}%
        \pgfpatharc{270}{90}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathclose%
        \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder body fill}}%
        \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
          \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder body shade}}%
          \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfusepath{discard}%
          \else % make shading:
            \begingroup
            \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\pgf@temp}
            \tikz@finish
          \fi
        \else
          \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@temp}%
          \pgfusepath{fill}%
        \fi
        %
        \pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
        \pgfpatharc{90}{-270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
        \pgfpathclose
        \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder end fill}}%
        \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
          \edef\pgf@temp{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/Cylinder end shade}}%
          \ifx\pgf@temp\pgfutil@empty
            \pgfusepath{discard}%
          \else % make shading: 
            \begingroup
            \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\pgf@temp}
            \tikz@finish
          \fi
        \else
          \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@temp}%
          \pgfusepath{fill}%
        \fi
      }%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{mycylinder/.style={shape=Cylinder, 
     cylinder uses custom fill, Cylinder end fill=blue!20,
     Cylinder body shade={left color=blue!60, right color=blue!90, middle color=blue!20},
     }
  }
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{scope}[color=purple]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1.3,0,0) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.3) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
 \fill[](0,0,0) circle(0.3pt) node[left]{$O$};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[color=blue]
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (1.3,0,0.3) node[anchor=south]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (0,1.,0.3) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0.3) -- (0,0,1.6) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\end{scope}
 \fill[](0,0,0.3) circle(0.3pt) node[left]{$G$};
% \draw[thick, dotted] ({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0.6)--({0.31*cos(90)},{0.31*sin(90)},0);
% \draw[thick, dotted] ({0.31*cos(270)},{0.31*sin(270)},0.6)--({0.31*cos(270)},{0.31*sin(270)},0);
\begin{scope}[opacity=0.6]
\node [aspect=6.7,rotate=90,mycylinder,minimum width=3.1cm,minimum height=4.17cm] 
at (0,0,0.178){}; % 
\end{scope}
\foreach \X [count=\n] in {0,0.3,0.6}
{
\path[name path=circle] (0,0,\X) circle(0.31);
\path[name path=line] (0,0,\X) -- ++(0.4cm,0);
\path[name path=mine] (0,0,\X) -- ++(-0.4cm,0);
\path [name intersections={of=circle and mine, name=li\n, total=\t}];

\path [name intersections={of=circle and line, name=i\n, total=\t}];
\ifnum\n=3
\else
\draw[dashed](i\n-1) arc(108:288:0.31);
\draw[-](i\n-1) arc(108:-72:0.31);
\fi
}
\draw[thick] (0,0,0.6) circle(0.31);
\draw[thick,dotted] (i1-1) -- (i3-1);
\draw[thick,dotted] (li1-1) -- (li3-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I added the amazing shading code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138834/121799) and added some amazing dashed and dotted lines. If someone has an amazing idea how to add an amazing tikzduck, please let me know.

Comment: thank you @marmot, how did you find the value of `minimum width=3.1cm,minimum height=4.12cm` and the coordinate value `(0,0,0.175)`

Comment: @moradov Just by guessing. BTW, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138834/121799) is a way to make 3D shading.

Comment: @marmot Truly amazing. +1 ;D

Comment: thank you @marmot, i want to add the command `\draw [densely dashed] (d) arc (0:180:5mm and 1.75mm);` such as used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360412), but **i don't understand what does mean `(0:180:5mm and 1.75mm)` **

Comment: @moradov These values specify the principal axes of an elliptical arc. You probably need to switch to rotated coordinates to draw the arc, but as usual there is the language barrier and I really have no clue what you want to achieve. Typing things bold does not help much, but perhaps google translate could.

Comment: I want to draw in dotted line or dashed line the arc of three circles  in the background

Comment: @marmot The answer could be even more amazing with more `amazing` in it :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4wbM.png